# SVG Animation Deployment

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have a site I am creating, and I have an SVG that I have animated. What I want is to make my animation not begin for a set time after the page has loaded. After *n* seconds, I want the SVG animation to begin. I have no clue where to begin and would love some assistance. Thanks.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/adamkerik/6c17ajqa/

```
svg {
    width: 700px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
svg path:nth-child(1) {
    stroke-dasharray: 110.6;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    animation: dash 3s linear;
}
svg path:nth-child(2) {
    stroke-dasharray: 320.6;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    animation: dash2 3s linear;
}
```

and etc. just here to allow my link to the JSFiddle, where the full code is located. Thanks!

Comment: Nope. You don't get to workaround the rules like that. There are many reasons we require code in the question itself rather than just a link, please respect those reasons and create a [mcve] here on Stack Overflow. Note that there is a Stack Snippets feature (available by clicking the `<>` icon) that has the same fields as jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always make the animation a class `.my-animation {...}`

and use the `setTimeout` function to add that class to an element after a specific time limit.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#my-svg").addClass('my-animation');
  }, 5000);
```

This would add the class `.my-animation` to the element `#my-svg` after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add begin="1s" to the animation or use the shorthand way your are using it which would be just adding de amount of seconds you want it to delay

> The animation shorthand CSS property applies an animation between
> styles. It is a shorthand for `animation-name`, `animation-duration`,
> `animation-timing-function`, `animation-delay`, `animation-iteration-count`,
> `animation-direction`, `animation-fill-mode`, and `animation-play-state`.

```
animation: 3s ease-in 1s infinite reverse both running slidein;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Answer (score 0):

In any case, if I am not using any library as anime.js, or vivus.js, which have their own features to set a delay, i use to point at the first path which will start the animation time-line and set a begin=5s (or whatever amount of time I wish for the animation to start). That works fine on non complex simple svg animations. Just like this one:

```
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 55 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#fcd736">
<g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 80)">
<rect width="10" height="20" rx="3">
<animate attributeName="height"
begin="2s" dur="4.3s"
values="20;45;57;80;64;32;66;45;64;23;66;13;64;56;34;34;2;23;76;79;20" calcMode="linear"
repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>
<rect x="15" width="10" height="80" rx="3">
<animate attributeName="height"
begin="3s" dur="2s"
values="80;55;33;5;75;23;73;33;12;14;60;80" calcMode="linear"
repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>
<rect x="30" width="10" height="50" rx="3">
<animate attributeName="height"
begin="4s" dur="1.4s"
values="50;34;78;23;56;23;34;76;80;54;21;50" calcMode="linear"
repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>
<rect x="45" width="10" height="30" rx="3">
<animate attributeName="height"
begin="5s" dur="2s"
values="30;45;13;80;56;72;45;76;34;23;67;30" calcMode="linear"
repeatCount="indefinite" />
</rect>
</g>
</svg>
```

```html
  <html>
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 55 80" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#fcd736">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 80)">
    <rect width="10" height="20" rx="3">
    <animate attributeName="height"
    begin="5s" dur="4.3s"
    values="20;45;57;80;64;32;66;45;64;23;66;13;64;56;34;34;2;23;76;79;20" calcMode="linear"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
    <rect x="15" width="10" height="80" rx="3">
    <animate attributeName="height"
    begin="5s" dur="2s"
    values="80;55;33;5;75;23;73;33;12;14;60;80" calcMode="linear"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
    <rect x="30" width="10" height="50" rx="3">
    <animate attributeName="height"
    begin="5s" dur="1.4s"
    values="50;34;78;23;56;23;34;76;80;54;21;50" calcMode="linear"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
    <rect x="45" width="10" height="30" rx="3">
    <animate attributeName="height"
    begin="5s" dur="2s"
    values="30;45;13;80;56;72;45;76;34;23;67;30" calcMode="linear"
    repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
    </g>
    </svg>
  </html>
```

notice how i have set a different start time to each object just in order to make it more in line with the stated above.